# Why textwidth-1cm works when I use todonotes

Tags: minipage, todonotes, textwidth

Here is a minimal example of my problem. If I remove the todonotes package I get `-1cm-1cmtest` on the output pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-1cm}
  test
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`todonotes` loads the `calc` package, which makes it possible to do calculations like that directly in the argument to a `minipage`.

Hence, you see the same thing if you comment/uncomment `\usepackage{calc}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-1cm}
  test
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```